# Node.js roadmap

Tags: node.js, backend

Я Frontend разработчик (4.5 лет опыта). Сейчас хочу перейти на FullStack (React + Node). Не знаю с чего начать)) Куча материалов, курсы, видео, хз че смотреть и что читать. Начал изучать доки, но хотелось бы составить какой-то роудмап, что нужно чтобы залететь на фуллстек вакансию и пройти собес) может кто-то что-то порекомендует. Хочу понять именно бест практики по архитектуре, правильные подходы, какие-то решения архитектурные и т.д. Роуты, контроллеры это я умею. Но хочется чего-то более продвинутого чтоли.

Comment: Если привыкли к JS, учите ноду и будет вам счастье. Учтите только, что асинхрон не везде используется, поэтому есть смысл какой-нибудь простенький Flask на python попробовать, потому что нода по дефолту на асинхрон заточена. По архитектурам, учите интеграции. Поднять проектик тривиальная задача, а вот собрать кучу микросервисов воедино — вот там начинается боль в backend.